# active voice for the phrase "is formed of"

Tags: active-voice

> The earth is formed of layers.

Can I change this sentence into active?

> Layers form the earth.

The Oxford advanced learner Dictionary says the word form is:
" [T, often passive] to produce sth in a particular way or make it have a particular shape]"
So I can't decide whether it is suitable to transform the phrase "formed of"  into active verb.

Comment: In the second example, "Layers form the earth". After all, you didn't write "the layers" in the first one.

Comment: Well, you can, but the result is not a verbal passive, but an adjectival passive. In "The earth is formed of layers", the word "formed" is an adjective, not a verb, hence it being called an 'adjectival passive'.

Comment: It would be like saying "layers of pasta form lasagna". It is grammatical, but it is a good example of when to use the passive. There is little reason to make the layers of pasta the subject of a transitive verb.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Yes.

Long answer: But I suggest you add what sort of layers.

For example:

- "Discuss...how these materials...form the layers that make up the crust of the Earth." -[Kentucky Coal Education](http://www.coaleducation.org/lessons/middle/doe/graphics.htm)
- "Chocolate, meringue, and whipped cream form the layers of this tall, silky dessert." -[Pinterest](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/194710383863368700/)

Active voice is often used to emphasize the subject.

Using a vague subject such as "layers" sort of defeats the purpose of using active voice.

Thus, my suggestion to expand the subject.

Good luck!